# how to print r,a and plot graph in python

Tags: python

I want to take `rsrp` and `time stamp` from text file and plot the graph for both where x-axis is `time stamp` y-axis is `rsrp`:

```
import re
import datetime
import os 
import os.path
from array import array
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
k=open(r'C:\Users\kirankumar\Downloads\log\offlineLogs\Log_20161027_190707\qxdm\new.txt', "r")
count=0
index=0
array = []
for line in k:
    count = count + 1
    r = re.findall('[r][s][r][p]*: -[0-9][0-9]*',line)
    if(r):
        k.seek(count-2)
        s = k.readline(50)
        a = re.findall('[0-9][0-9]*:[0-9][0-9]*:[0-9][0-9]*.[0-9]*',s)
        k.seek(count+3)
        if(a):
            array.append([])
            if(array([index][0]) != r):
                array[index+1][0] = r
                array[index+1][1] = a
                print (r,a)
```

Comment: What is the content of .txt file ? You can look into the [pyplot](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html).

Comment: it is the code of many lines , hence want to find 'rsrp' and 'timestamp' then i want to plot it